# What is wrong with my vb.net webmethod?

Tags: sql, vb.net

This webmethod retrieves plist, firstaname, lastname, orgid from database then insert 2 lines in 2 different tables. 1st sql is fine - 2nd doesnt run

```vb
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Register(ByVal meetingid As String, ByVal myid As String, ByVal PartType As Integer, ByVal startDate As String) As String
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("EPBconnection").ConnectionString)
    Dim sSQL As String
    Dim plistid As String = ""
    Dim LastName As String = ""
    Dim FirstName As String = ""
    Dim orgID As String = ""

    'get plistID
    sSQL = "select pl.PLIST_ID"
    sSQL = sSQL + " From PERSON_LIST pl"
    sSQL = sSQL + " Where MTG_ID = '" + meetingid + "'"
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(sSQL, connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    While myReader.Read()
        plistid = myReader("PLIST_ID").ToString()
    End While
    connection.Close()

    'get firstname, lastname, orgid
    sSQL = "SELECT p.LASTNAME, p.FIRSTNAME, p.ORGA_ID FROM PERSON p WHERE PERSON_ID = '" + myid + "'"
    myCommand = New SqlCommand(sSQL, connection)
    connection.Open()
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
    While myReader.Read()
        LastName = myReader("LASTNAME").ToString()
        FirstName = myReader("FIRSTNAME").ToString()
        orgID = myReader("ORGA_ID").ToString()
    End While
    connection.Close()

    Return "You are registered for this meeting"

End Function
```

When i remove the following it returns the string but otherwise it doesnt (compiles without errors either way):

```
While myReader.Read()
    LastName = myReader("LASTNAME").ToString()
    FirstName = myReader("FIRSTNAME").ToString()
    orgID = myReader("ORGA_ID").ToString()
End While
```

The problem seems to be coming from myReader.Read()??? I dont understand why

Comment: You should consider to use Stored Procedures instead of wired SQL and adding some exception handling to your code

Comment: The big think I noticed immediately that is wrong is that **your code is vulnerable to sql injection.** You're practically _begging_ to get hacked.

Comment: Oh boy the SQL injection errors. Please look into parameter substitution. Also, if your problem is with SQL, you should provide us with the actual query that is sent to the server and the error it produces, not just a wall of code that composes the query.

Comment: The next thing I noticed is that you'd don't close the connection correctly. If an exception happens (and they will), you'll leave open connections hanging out and eventually cause a denial of service situation to your database. You need to make sure your connections are closed inside a finally block.

Comment: That wile loop should be an `If`

Comment: The sql is fine - it has been check and works

Comment: I dont know about begging to be hacked. What could i do to improve security? The webservice is password protected.

Comment: Magnus, why should it be if? all the tutorials said to use while

Comment: Magnus - nevermind, changed it to if but that doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

```
 orgID = myReader("ORGA_ID").ToString()
```

You have defined orgId as Integer;

```
  Dim orgID As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry every1 the problem was solved by itself over night. Still dont know what the problem was. LOL